# CSS Is Not Working for Firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

I have a site that is not displaying correctly for Firefox. Works perfectly for IE Edge, Chrome and Safari.  It's like Firefox is not rendering any of the css.

I even disabled all the plugins and changed the theme to WP's default TwentySeventeen.  Still same problem.

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it.

[css not working for Firefox](https://sweetsfest.com/)

Comment: Right click anywhere on the page, then click Inspect Element. You will see a list of JS warning, saying that your ressources have been blocked, so they are not loading using FF. *EDIT*: If you try to open one of your ressources from the console, Firefox doesn't let you access it

Comment: Is this only certain elements that aren't displaying correctly? Or do you mean the entire CSS styling isn't working?

Comment: In a nutshell, the site was hosted on Godaddy. Then the blacklist happened. So I set up a site at Siteground using the default Wordpress install and them. In saying none of the files have been migrated over yet.  I then changed the dns at Godaddy to point to Site Ground and the page breaks just like it does now.  I am not sure why or if the SSL Certificate is the issue or what but I am baffled.  To answer your question, it seems that Javascript and css are not rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the fact your website is analysed having a dangerous and deceptive content by firefox. I disabled the option 'block dangerous and deceptive content' in 'Privacy & security' within my Firefox options. Work well afterwards.

Have a look to your SSL certificate for your https url. It may be the cause.

Comment: So do you think the SSL certificate might be bad?  How can I check to know it's bad?

Comment: I have checked your ssl certificate. It seems good. I have checked your website with google yur website through transparency report and I get this issue: Current status
warning
Some pages on this site are unsafe

The site https://sweetsfest.com/ contains harmful content, including pages that:

    Try to trick visitors into sharing personal info or downloading software

Unsafe content might only appear on some pages of a website. Check the URL of the specific directory or webpage you want to visit for more detailed safety info.

Comment: you do not seem to have virus tho https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload

Comment: you can try this https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en

Comment: with this last link you can say to google that your site is clean and does not try to fish

Comment: And last thing, I do not know if your are from this agency (the agency that develops the website)? https://levitateagency.com/ but I have the same issue with their website.

Comment: I am not the owner of levitateagency.com but it too was one of the sites that was blacklisted but after moving that site over to Site Ground it does not breaks visually as sweetsfest.com did and that's what's confusing me.  

As for the google links, I did submit to google those two domains as being clean (including a 3rd one).  I do not know how long it will take them but the scan for sweetsfest.com was done August 13th but the clean site was done earlier this week.

Comment: Update: levitateagency.com  last scan was August 22nd but it gave me a clean report.  So I don't know why  you are getting the same issue.

Comment: ok please let us know when google has replied to you. Good luck